# Use dot product to find the angle at vertex $A$ in the triangle $ABC$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Consider the points $A(0,0,0)$, $B(1,2,3)$ and $C(-3,0,0)$. Use dot product to find the angle at vertex A in the triangle ABC

I solved the problem this way:

$\overrightarrow{AB} = <1,2,3>$

$\overrightarrow{AC} = <-3,0,0>$

$cos(\theta)= \frac{A \bullet B}{|A||B|} = \frac{-3}{\sqrt{14}\sqrt{9}}$

$\theta = cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{14}}\right)$

This doesn't seem like it is correct, though?  Did I make a mistake?  I'm primarily confused by finding the angle at vertex $A$.  Is $A$ the vertex that connects $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$?

Comment: Why do you suddenly drop the $cos$?

Comment: Oops that was a typo

Comment: It seems correct to me ---   

 if the x-coordinate of $B$ was zero the angle would be exactly right,  

as it is the x-coordinate of $B$ is slightly positive so the angle is slightly obtuse.

Comment: Indeed. The arccos $\approx$ 105.5 degrees. It's correct.